# Rstudio plots in seperate window after update

Tags: plot, rstudio

I updated my Rstudio this week tp RStudio 2022.07.1+554 "Spotted Wakerobin". When I start plotting graphs with this version they are plotted in a separate window. I have tried:
`dev.off()`
and unchecking "Show output inline for all R Markdown documents", but both sadly to no avail.

Are there any other possible solutions to stop Rstudio from plotting in a separate window rather? I would like it to return to the Plots pane where it used to plot any figures or graphs.